# C# Design Patterns, what is the best way to write my web application?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm writing a web application that can get good results and grow up in the future. If it happens, a team will program it and not only me. So, I'd like to find some design patterns for my programming.

I don't know if I should write method names in my language or in English, how should I name my databases, etc, etc.

Someone knows about a good guide for that purpose?

Comment: This is pretty vague, could I suggest that you be a bit more explicit. What language you write in is more of a paradigm or practice, patterns would be more along the lines of cqrs or adapter pattern or something. Could you be a bit more specific to what you want advice on?

Comment: For example: my mother tongue is Brazilian portuguese. BUT I know that some programmers in Brazil write code only in English. However, I have some specific methods with very special functions that I couldn't translate to English. I just wanna design my programming based on any Microsoft C# design pattern to avoid someone to point me in the future as messy programmer. Do you know any link with guides about design patterns?

Comment: @Rubia Gardini : the best way is to join (even as junior developer) any well-skilled team and work together at least few years - then you'll get an experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sll's answer will probably prove the most resourceful for you, but I love your strive to get better.  We make our interns read Head First Design Patterns: [http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) (or it's included if you have a Safari Online account).

That book is a pretty rock solid overview and a pretty decent foundation for design patterns.  All the code is technically in Java, but it translates well to any of the OO languages.

As to your question about what language to use (again, as it's not really a design pattern as a cultural paradigm IMO), I would simply do your best to consider your time to develop the software with what you anticipate your audience to be.  The industry norm is to try to program in the same language that the CLR is written in (typically this is English) but I will simply offer this point/counterpoint:

- If you intend to open source or outsource your code it could make it very limiting to the developers that could continue a Portuguese paradigm.
- A code base that is created quickly and elegantly in your language is better than a code base that languishes in English (and takes way too long to release) just to conform to the industry.

As a final comment, if it was written mostly in English, but you named the few methods that you mentioned in Portuguese, no decent developer should mind working on that (or refactoring later) so long as you comment what the method does adequately.

Granted this link is the Microsoft way, but it should be helpful to your question also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Comment: Hi Rikon, your answer is really helpful, thanks a lot for the book and the points you mentioned, I feel much more confident now